# vercel express js app using @aws-sdk/client-s3 crashes

Tags: node.js, express, aws-sdk, serverless, vercel

I am trying to deploy a expressjs app to vercel serverless. I am using @aws-sdk/client-s3 3.478.0. It works on local dev machine but I get this error when deploying to vercel. If I remove the code that includes @aws-sdk, the error goes away. I tried installing @smithy/config-resolver, but to no avail. Anybody seen this error before?

```
Cannot find module '@smithy/config-resolver'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/S3Client.js
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post/dist-cjs/createPresignedPost.js
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post/dist-cjs/index.js
- /var/task/controllers/user/presign.js
- /var/task/routes/user.js
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/task/___now_launcher.js
- /var/runtime/index.mjs
Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
Child exited with error exit status 1INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 523.65 ms   Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Cannot find module '@smithy/config-resolver'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/S3Client.js
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post/dist-cjs/createPresignedPost.js
- /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post/dist-cjs/index.js
- /var/task/controllers/user/presign.js
- /var/task/routes/user.js
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/task/___now_launcher.js
- /var/runtime/index.mjs
Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 651.35 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError
```